# UIView reports its center differently in two different methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView which I create with `initWithFrame` and it displays fine, exactly where I want.

To test some touch interactivity, I did the following:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"center: %f",self.center.x);
 }
```

When I press the view (and other views like this one), they all correctly log a number that makes sense as their center point in the coordinate space of the views' superview.

However, when I do the same log statement inside the `initWithFrame` method, `self.center.x` does not report a coordinate in the view's superview's space. Instead, it reports the point that would be the bounds center, i.e. if the view is 100px wide, it reports `50`, for all views.

What I don't understand is that these views are not moving and the frame is clearly set at the beginning of `initWithFrame` since it is passed a frame `CGRect` and the view displays in the right place. So why doesn't it report its center properly only in that method?

Comment: Could you post the initWithFrame: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `-initWithFrame:`, your view has not yet been added to a superview.

(Some other code later on adds it to a superview -- either as part of the nib loading code, or manually.)